How to click on subgrid item after the search
enter image description here
My question is -
after successful login into dynamics 365
searching record using below command
xrmApp.Grid.Search ("A datum corporation)
ISSUE
after this , i want to click on Main phone (yellow highlighted)
Can some help me which command to use - as i new to EASYREPRO FRAMEWORK.
Thanks in advance.
FOR SEARCH I DID
xrmApp.Grid.Search ("A datum corporation)
ISSUE
after this , i want to click on Main phone (yellow highlighted)
Can some help me which command to use - as i new to EASYREPRO FRAMEWORK.
Thanks in advance.
